# Unexpected Value 'VoteComponent' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular / testing in general. Been working through the Angular documentation regarding testing and I am struggling. Have searched this site for answers but have been unsuccessful. I have also tried adding additional imports to the `app.module.ts` file.

Using Jasmine, receiving this error:
`Error: Unexpected value 'VoteComponent' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'`

The component.ts file is very basic:

```
export class VoteComponent { 

  totalVotes = 0; 

  upVote() { 
    this.totalVotes++;
  }

  downVote() { 
    this.totalVotes--;
  }
}
```

The spec.ts file: (I have not written code for `downVote()`)

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { VoteComponent } from './vote.component';

describe ('VoteComponent', () => { 
  let comp: VoteComponent;

  beforeEach(() => { 
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
        declarations: [VoteComponent],    
    });

    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(VoteComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;

  });

  it('should increment total votes when upvoted', () => { 

    comp.upVote();

    expect(comp.totalVotes).toBe(1); 

  });
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you add `@Component` metadata to your component?

Comment: No. How it is written above is all that is in the component.ts file.

Comment: You have to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular only respects classes adorned by `@Component`, `@Directive` or `@Pipe` decorator in the `declarations` array.

So you have to add metadata to your class:

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'vote-component',
  template: 'some template'
})
export class VoteComponent { 

  totalVotes = 0; 

  upVote() { 
    this.totalVotes++;
  }

  downVote() { 
    this.totalVotes--;
  }
}
```